# How may I generate in Dafny 3.1.0 an executable file that reads a file?

Tags: c#, parsing, dafny

The following is a simple parser and an example of use in Dafny

```
module Parsing {
  datatype Option<A> = Some(some: A) | None

  datatype Parser<A> = Parser(run: string -> Option<(A, string)>)

  function method Const<A>(a: A): Parser<A>
  {
    Parser(s => Some((a, s)))
  }

  function method Map<A, B>(p: Parser<A>, f: A -> B): Parser<B>
  {
    Parser((s: string) => var t := p.run(s);
                           if t.None?
                            then None
                            else Some((f(t.some.0), t.some.1)))
  }

  function method SatChar(pred: char -> bool): Parser<char>
  {
    Parser((s: string) => if |s| == 0 then None
                          else if pred(s[0]) then Some((s[0], s[1..]))
                          else None)
  }

  function method Or<A>(p1: Parser<A>, p2: Parser<A>): Parser<A>
  {
    Parser((s: string) => (var t: Option<(A,string)> := p1.run(s);
                           if t.Some?
                            then t
                            else p2.run(s)))
  }

  function method Char(c: char): Parser<char>
  {
    SatChar(c2 => c == c2)
  }

  function method Digit(): Parser<char>
  {
    SatChar(c => '0' <= c <= '9')
  }

  function method Letter(): Parser<char>
  {
    SatChar(c => 'A' <= c <= 'Z' || 'a' <= c <= 'z' || c == '_')
  }

  function method Bind<A, B>(pa: Parser<A>, pb: A -> Parser<B>): Parser<B>
  {
    Parser((s: string)
            => (var t: Option<(A,string)> := pa.run(s);
                if t.None? then None else pb(t.some.0).run(t.some.1)))
  }

  function method Seq<A, B, C>(pa: Parser<A>, pb: Parser<B>, f: (A, B) -> C): Parser<C>
  {
    var cont: A -> B -> Parser<C> :=
      (a: A) => (b: B) => Const(f(a,b));
    Bind<A, C>(pa, (a: A) => Bind<B, C>(pb, cont(a)))
  }

  function method Skip<A, B>(pa: Parser<A>, pb: Parser<B>): Parser<A>
  {
    Seq<A, B, A>(pa, pb, (a, b) => a)
  }

  function method Then<A, B>(pa: Parser<A>, pb: Parser<B>): Parser<B>
  {
    Seq<A, B, B>(pa, pb, (a, b) => b)
  }

  function method SkipOptional<A, B>(pa: Parser<A>, pb: Parser<B>): Parser<A>
  {
    Or(Skip(pa, pb), pa)
  }

  function method SkipWS<A>(p: Parser<A>): Parser<A>
  {
    var ws: Parser<string> := ZeroOrMore(Or(Or(Char(' '), Char('\t')), Char('\n')));
    Then(ws, Skip(p, ws))
  }

  function method ZeroOrMoreLim<A>(p: Parser<A>, limit: nat): Parser<seq<A>>
    decreases limit
  {
    if limit == 0
    then Const([])
    else Or(OneOrMoreLim<A>(p, limit - 1), Const([]))
  }

  function method OneOrMoreLim<A>(p: Parser<A>, limit: nat): Parser<seq<A>>
    decreases limit
  {
    if limit == 0
    then Const([])
    else Seq<A, seq<A>, seq<A>>(p, ZeroOrMoreLim(p, limit - 1), (a, aa) => [a] + aa)
  }

  function method OneOrMore<A>(p: Parser<A>): Parser<seq<A>>
  {
    OneOrMoreLim(p, 100)
  }

  function method ZeroOrMore<A>(p: Parser<A>): Parser<seq<A>>
  {
    ZeroOrMoreLim(p, 100)
  }

  function method ZCombLim<A>(f: Parser<A> -> Parser<A>, limit: nat): Parser<A>
  decreases limit
  {
    if limit == 0
    then Parser(s => None)
    else f(ZCombLim(f, limit - 1))
  }

  function method ZComb<A>(f: Parser<A> -> Parser<A>): Parser<A>
  {
    ZCombLim(f, 32)
  }

  function method Parse<A>(parser: Parser<A>, str: string): Option<A>
  {
    var t := parser.run(str);
    if t.None? then None else if |t.some.1| > 0 then None else Some(t.some.0)
  }


  class FileSystem {
    static method {:extern} ReadFile(name: array<char>) returns (contents: array?<char>)
  }

  method ParseFile<A>(parser: Parser<A>, filename: string) returns (res: Option<A>)
  {
    var fname := new char[|filename|](i requires 0 <= i < |filename| => filename[i]);
    var contents := FileSystem.ReadFile(fname);
    if contents == null { return None; }
    var parseResult := Parse(parser, contents[..]);
    return parseResult;
  }

  /* default export Public { */
  /*   Parser, */
  /*   Const, */
  /*   SatChar, */
  /*   Or, */
  /*   Char, */
  /*   Digit, */
  /*   Letter, */
  /*   Then, */
  /*   Map, */
  /*   Skip, */
  /*   Seq, */
  /*   ZeroOrMore, */
  /*   OneOrMore, */
  /*   Parse, */
  /*   ParseFile */
  /* } */
}

module Example {
  import opened Parsing

  datatype SExpr = Atom(string) | List(seq<SExpr>)

  method Main() {
    // single characters
    print Parse(Digit(), "5"); // Some(5)
    print "\n";
    print Parse(Digit(), "X"); // None
    print "\n";
    var digitOrLetter: Parser<char> := Or(Digit(), Letter());
    print Parse(digitOrLetter, "X"); // Some(X)
    print "\n";
    print Parse(digitOrLetter, "+"); // None
    print "\n";

    // identifiers
    var id: Parser<string> := Seq(Letter(),
                                  ZeroOrMore(digitOrLetter),
                                  (s, ss) => [s] + ss);
    print Parse(id, "x23"); // Some(x23)
    print "\n";
    print Parse(id, "a_s"); // Some(a_s)
    print "\n";
    print Parse(id, "12a"); // None
    print "\n";

    // s-expressions
    var sexpr: Parser<SExpr> := ZComb((sexp: Parser<SExpr>)
      =>
      var atom: Parser<SExpr> := Map(OneOrMore(digitOrLetter), s => Atom(s));
      var lst: Parser<SExpr> :=
        Skip(Then(Char('('),
                  Map(ZeroOrMore(sexp), l => List(l))),
            Char(')'));
      SkipWS(Or(atom, lst)));

    print Parse(sexpr, "x23");     // Some(Atom(x23))
    print "\n";
    print Parse(sexpr, "(a b c)"); // Some(List(Atom(a),Atom(b),Atom(c)))
    print "\n";
    print Parse(sexpr, "((a) b)"); // Some(List(List(Atom(a)),Atom(b)))
    print "\n";
    print Parse(sexpr, "((");      // None
    print "\n";

    print Parse(ZeroOrMore(sexpr), "a b c"); // Some(List(Atom(a),Atom(b),Atom(c)))
    print "\n";
  }
}
```

I would like to generate a .exe that reads a file and prints the results, but I get the error:

```
Errors compiling program:
(2188,42): error CS0117: 'FileSystem' does not contain a definition for 'ReadFile'
```

I need some help with the ReadFile method and also with the generation a .exe. This is the error that I get when I tried

```
PS C:\Users\jiplucap\Desktop\dafny-3.1.0-x64-win> & "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.EXE" "c:\Users\jiplucap\.vscode\extensions\correctnesslab.dafny-vscode-1.5.0\out\resources\dafny\Dafny.dll" "c:\Users\jiplucap\Desktop\proving-read.dfy" /verifyAllModules /compile:3 /spillTargetCode:1 /out:bin\proving-read

Dafny program verifier finished with 20 verified, 0 errors
Wrote textual form of target program to proving-read.cs
Errors compiling program:
(2188,42): error CS0117: 'FileSystem' does not contain a definition for 'ReadFile'
```

Thanks in advance,
Paqui